# Use AudioKit Node to AVCaptureSession as audio inputs

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avcapturesession, audiokit

I'm developing app for sound effects. I use AudioKit and I got a needed result for recoding voice. Now I want to add sound effect to voice while video is recording. I can record video with default voice, but I don't know how I can add effect to voice from video.

I use AVCaptureSession for video recording and I get audio stream like this:

```
self.audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)    

if let audioDevice = self.audioDevice {
   self.audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
            
   if captureSession.canAddInput(self.audioInput!) {
       captureSession.addInput(self.audioInput!)
   } else {
       throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
   }
}
```

But I want to set to captureSession input AVAudioNode, because AudioKit works with it.

I will be glad for any help. Thanks